# The data has being rotating left by one bit, each time when I read the data

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, python-3

[image]

am interfacing EM-18 rfid reader  to raspberry pi 3 through USB. The data has being rotating left  by one bit, each time when I read the data

Comment: **DO NOT** post images post text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data.read(12)` always reads exactly 12 bytes from the serial interface - if the sent card id is longer or shorter it will mess up the next read.

If its always off by one on the next read, you probably need 13 bytes here - but it would be more robust to read until a certain character (eg. `\n` newline)